# implementation of os python library in blender python api

Tags: python, operating-system, blender

I had to create and write to a text file from Blender python script. the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) says that with the `fdopen()` function one can open the txt file as a stream in your code.

However, `fdopen()` does not seem to be implemented in python api in blender. Instead, it is commented as #supply `fdopen()`. you can actually do what `fdopen()` must do with another function `open()` which is a built-in function of the python api (seemingly does not belong to os).

Also, if I use `os.open()` in blender, it returns an integer instead of a file. Does this all mean that the Blender os module implementation is different from the 'native' python os?

I mean, this library is 're-written' in C by blender devs? I have no computer science background, so I cannot really understand, why that is happening, if I am right in my assumption. My understanding is that BDFL has written os module in C and it should now perfectly work for everyone, everywhere. why not simply take it and embed in python api in blender? can someone explain this to me in some detail?

Comment: For Blender questions you can also use: https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bruno hey, thanks. from my experience, programming questions are answered better and with higher quality here because at blen.stack people are usually anticipating questions about blender itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender uses default python os module. [os.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) returns a file descriptor (`int`); builtin global function [open](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) returns file object - that's what you should use for your regular file access.

Comment: okay but then I am confused. function signatures ARE different in the both. fdopen() returns a file in default python os, and is not impelemented in blender python api. or am I wrong?

Comment: It's just the default python `os` module, why do you think it is different in any way? `os` module is, by its nature, very operating system specific, most of its functions are 1:1 match for C runtime functions OS provide. E.g. C `fdopen` on linux is https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen function to use `int` file descriptor as `FILE*`. What it returns is still isn't python file object but libc `FILE*`; unless you need to pass it to C code that expects a `FILE*` it is useless to you. Use python's `open` (better in `with open("filename", "w") as f:` block for automatic `close` handling).

Comment: Perhaps you're comparing it with python2 while blender uses python3?

Comment: I think you were right in your second comment. So, fdopen() returns a C-relevant output, that's why it is returning the useless integer if you're in python. thanks!